# Insert an element into an array sorted according to frequency, then sort the array by frequency again

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I was asked asked to write an O(n) function, `insertRanked(int[] list, int item)`, to insert an element into an array sorted by frequency (I have written a boolean function to check if `int[] list` is sorted by frequency). After inserting the element into the array, the array is then sorted again by frequency.

For example, `insertRanked([65, 65, 65, 65, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 987, 987, 2, 2, 40], 2)` should produce `[65, 65, 65, 65, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 987, 987, 40]`.

Is this possible to do in O(n)? I have thought of storing the elements and their counts into a `LinkedHashMap` and using `Collections.sort()` but the time complexity of `Collections.sort()` is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: what is the range of the numbers that are in array?

Comment: depends on the input array (int[] list)

Comment: I know that depends on the that list but the range must be specified in the question

Comment: You can't insert values into Java arrays. The declaration `int[] list` is funny.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach to start you off could be based on count.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

    public class SortCount {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int nums[] = {([65, 65, 65, 65, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 987, 987, 2, 2, 40};
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if(counts.containsKey(nums[
                    Integer c = counts.get(nums[i]) + 1;
                    counts.put(nums[i], c);
                }
                else {
                    counts.put(nums[i],1);
                }
            }

            ValueComparator<Integer,Integer> bvc = new ValueComparator<Integer,Integer>(counts);
            TreeMap<Integer,Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>(bvc);
            sortedMap.putAll(counts);

            ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(Integer i : sortedMap.keySet()) {
                for(int c = 0; c < sortedMap.get(i); c++) {
                    output.add(i);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(output.toString());
        }
    }

//Which uses a Comparator class to compare the values in a Map:



 import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class ValueComparator<T1,T2 extends Comparable<T2>> implements Comparator<T1> {
        Map<T1,T2> base;
        public ValueComparator(Map<T1,T2> base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(T1 k1, T1 k2) {
            T2 val1 = base.get(k1);
            T2 val2 = base.get(k2);

            return val1.compareTo(val2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i don't think tree map has linear  time complexity..it's insertion and deletion each take O(log n) time making it O(nlogn).The op asked a linear time complexity solution..But i haven't figured out yet if it can be done in linear time

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array is already sorted by frequency, of course it's possible to do in `O(n)`. Traverse the array once to figure out what the change is in frequency for the element in question (in your example, 2 goes from a frequency of 2 to 3). In the second iteration, insert the numbers one by one into a new array until you reach the last element with the target frequency for the inserted element. Insert the target element the appropriate number of times and continue inserting the rest, skipping the target element.

Comment: If you keep the "previous minimum run-length" and the start of runs of the current length, you can use "array copies" (plus one "insert") where advantageous.